# How to customize calendar control?

Tags: asp.net

I am displaying calendar using calendar control.

Each date is displayed as Link button.

But i want only last 30 days(dates) from current date, to be enabled for client click. on those days i will write some code on SelectionChanged event. But goal is other dates must be disabled for click.

They should not have link button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write custom day rendering function and attach it to   `DayRender`   event of your Calendar control. It should be pretty simple.

#### Something like:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="C1" runat="server" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" />
```

#### and

```
private void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date < BeginningOfDateRange ||
        e.Day.Date > EndOfDateRange)
    {
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
        e.Day.IsSelectable = False
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the **DayRender event** of the calendar control to customize the appearance of each day displayed. This event handler is called for each day displayed by the calendar control:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender">
</asp:Calendar>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Day.IsSelectable = IsDateValid(e.Day.Date);
}
```

Where **IsDateValid()** is a method you implement to check whether a date should be enabled or not.